# Creating Navigation Drawer in Fragment

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am trying to create a Left Navigation for a Fragment, using instruction from this link http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html#top. The problem is in this line, but I don't know how to fix it

```
mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Here is the full code:

```
public class BattleFieldFragment extends Fragment {
private String[] mLeftDrawerTitles;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_battle_field, parent, false);
    mLeftDrawerTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.bar_left_drawer);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.layout_battle_field_drawer);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.layout_battle_field_left_drawer);

    // Set the adapter for the list view
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.drawer_battle_field, mLeftDrawerTitles);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
    return v;
}
```

I did not put on xml codes; please let me know if more information is needed.

Here is `activity_battle_field.xml` as requested:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout_battle_field_drawer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- The main content view -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_battle_field"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!-- The navigation drawer -->
 <!-- should not be larger than 320 to show content -->
<ListView android:id="@+id/layout_battle_field_left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#111" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Can you paste the error log?

Comment: @androbat it simply shut down, didn't show any error in the log :(

Comment: Than why are you sure that the problem is in the list adapter? Try pasting the layout xml file.

Comment: @androbat When I comment out that line, the application runs and everything seems to be working, except that the Left drawer is empty (because setAdapter() was commented out). There are quite a few XML files, is there a particular one that you are interested in?

Comment: This one: R.layout.activity_battle_field

Comment: The description in the link is for an activity. I am not positive that the same thing works for fragments.

Comment: @androbat I have pasted the code as you instructed.

Comment: @MalaKa do you happen to know a Navigation drawer for fragment? I was recommended to do everything in Fragment instead of interchanging between Activity and Fragment

Comment: As far as I know, you normally have one NavigationDrawer per Activity. But I am not sure if it also works for Fragments. And I'm sorry, I don't know a NavigationDrawer that is designed to work in a Fragment. I can only imagine that it doesn't work with Fragments because using it in Fragments might result in having two NavigationDrawers on the screen at the same time, which does not make sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

You're working on the example built for the Activity and now trying to implement it in Fragment. I will give you a short example how I did it in my app, you just have to change layout names to fit yours.

*activity_main.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.skoric.tdm.app.MainActivity" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:name="com.skoric.tdm.drawer.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

*fragment_navigation_drawer.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/drawerList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/drawer_list_selector"
    android:background="@color/white" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

*NavigationDrawerFragment.java*

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle bundle)
{
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container);

    drawerListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.drawerList);

    ...

    drawerListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    return view;
}
```

But that's just a part of the code, I personally suggest that you start an empty project in Eclipse or Android Studio and select to automatically create an activity with the navigation drawer implemented and then follow their implementation to create one for your own app.